# Getting Spaces to Play Nicely with C++ Input Streams

Tags: c++, string, inputstream, standard-library

First consider this sample C++ code:

```
std::string input1, input2, input3;
std::cout << "Enter Input 1: ";
std::cin >> input1;
std::cout << std::endl << "Enter Input 2: ";
std::cin >> input2;
std::cout << std::endl << "Enter Input 3: ";
std::cin >> input3;
```

If for input1 I enter something like "Good day neighbors" then input1 is set to "Good", input2 is set to "day" and input 3 is set to "neighbors". Im not even given the opportunity to set values for input2 and input3.

So my question is: How can I input a string of text that include spaces into a single string without it (for lack of better terminology) breaking up and overflowing into subsequent calls to the input stream?

Thanks in advance to any and all answers received.

Comment: fgets.  Is a dupe will get link shortly..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555731/how-to-take-whitespace-in-input-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over cin line by line in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c)

Comment: Neither of those is a duplicate. brumScouse, your question regards a fixed size C-style string as well as an alternative to scanf. I'm working with a C++ Standard library string. The answer would not have helped me. Jerry, your question was asked by someone who already knew getline() existed whereas I did not. Thanks for the links just the same.

Comment: s.: It is a dup of the second one. You just did not know that you wanted a line based solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `std::getline`:

```
std::getline(std::cin, input1);
...
std::getline(std::cin, input2);
...
std::getline(std::cin, input3);
```