# Scan strings into array in C

Tags: c, vector, scanf, c-strings

I want to scan these values to an array. I created a struct and the array is of that type.
My problem is that, when i compile, all the ints work fine, but when it comes to the strings it doesn't let me insert any values and jumps to the next instruction of my code. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
printf("\nInsert id: ");
scanf("%i", &vDisp[MAXDISP].idComp);
printf("\nInsert serial number: ");
scanf("%i", &vDisp[MAXDISP].serial);
printf("\nInsert production year: ");
scanf("%i", &vDisp[MAXDISP].year);

printf("\nInsert brand: ");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &vDisp[MAXDISP].brand);
printf("\nInsert type: ");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &vDisp[MAXDISP].type);
printf("\nInsert model: ");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &vDisp[MAXDISP].model);
printf("\nInsert OS: ");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &vDisp[MAXDISP].system);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all those vDisp.XXX are string typed? A little more code would be helpful because MAXDISP could be out of bounds, since your working with a referece &Array, it may be causing the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input string through scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782136/input-string-through-scanf)

Comment: What's the value of `MAXDISP`, and how does it relate to the size of the array?

Comment: @user3121023 Note that with `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", &vDisp[MAXDISP].brand);` it does not allow a user to enter an empty line.  User can type `<Enter>` repeatedly without the function returning.

Comment: MAXDISP value is 20. But that's supposed to limit the number of values in the array, right?

Answer (score 1):

What about `scanf("%s",str)` ?  where str is a char array.

Here is the custom getline function

```
char * getline(char cp) {
    char * line = malloc(100), * linep = line;
    size_t lenmax = 100, len = lenmax;
    int c;


    if(line == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for(;;) {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        if(c == EOF)
            break;

        if(--len == 0) {
            len = lenmax;
            intptr_t diff = line - linep;
            char * linen = realloc(linep, lenmax *= 2);

            if(linen == NULL) {
                free(linep);
                return NULL;
            }
            line = linen + diff;
            linep = linen;
        }

        if((*line++ = c) == cp)
            break;
    }
    *line = '\0';
    return linep;
}
```

`cp` is the character upto which you wanna read at a line.

Comment: The problem is that way it doesn't include spaces when it scans

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho.: If it worked please upvote or select the answer.it helps future users

Comment: Note: that by allowing `realloc()`, without restriction on size, this approach allows a user to exploit excessive consumption of memory resources.  Better to restrict user input size to a sane limit.

Comment: I'll try it in some minutes. Thanks!